# How to find Time invariance with two or negative terms, signals.

Tags: functions, signal-processing, invariance

I'm trying to figure out whether the input $x(t)$ and output $y(t)$ is time invariant. I was able to solve the other questions but I ran into a problem with this one. I'm bad at editing these so I posted it as a picture

$$y(t)=\int_{t}^{t+1}x(\tau-\alpha)d\tau$$

where $\alpha$ is a constant.

This is how I usually solve these. I'm posting an example from my text book

[Textbook examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps2ro.jpg)

I just don't know how to do this question cause it has two terms, and it's not the t variable, and there's a constant. I'd really appreciate the help please.

Comment: Look how I edited the question. It would be better to learn some Latex...

Comment: Latex? I haven't really heard of that before, I'll look into that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output to $x_1(t)$ is
$$y_1(t)=\int_{t}^{t+1}x_1(\tau-\alpha)d\tau$$
Now select $x_2(t)=x_1(t-t_0)$
$$y_2(t)=\int_{t}^{t+1}x_1(\tau-t_0-\alpha)d\tau$$
Choose $\tau'=\tau-t_0\Rightarrow d\tau=d\tau'.$
  $$y_2(t)=\int_{t-t_0}^{t-t_0+1}x_1(\tau'-\alpha)d\tau'=y_1(t-t_0)$$

Comment: I get it, you replaced the τ with τ-t0. I thought I'd have to figure out a way to  substitute it with a variable. So this is time invariant. The only thing I didn't get was why you didn't replace t with t-t0 in the first y2(t) expression like you did in the last one. Was it just not necessary?

Comment: I just calculated the output the shifted input in the first one, according to the definition of the system.

Comment: Oh, okay. I get it great now, thanks